# How to make click button in telegram

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot

I want to make a link button in Telegram browser, how should I a path follow
e.g

[The output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1HHK.png)

[The output i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQLtp.png)

```
token="xxx"
url=f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"
data={"chat_id": f"{chat_id}","text":f"""
Konum: https://maps.google.com/?q=37.335637,40.705739&ll=37.335637,40.705739&z=8
"""}
requests.post(url,data).json()
```

**I hope I explained, thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the link like this

```
data={
    "chat_id": f"{chat_id}",
    "text":f" Konum: <a href=\"https://maps.google.com/?q=37.335637,40.705739&ll=37.335637,40.705739&z=8\">link</a>",
    "parse_mode": "html"
}
```

you can also use markdown as

```
data = {
        "chat_id":chat_id, 
        "text":f"Konum: [link](https://maps.google.com/?q=37.335637,40.705739&ll=37.335637,40.705739&z=8)",
        "parse_mode": "markdown",
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work
[output](https://prnt.sc/dSLh6tmOskLH)

Comment: sorry my mistake. try now. I have updated the answer.